# How to delete a mongodb db whose name includes ":"?

Tags: mongodb

I create a db which name includes `:` by accident. Sadly, I can't select it, delete now, but I can copy it which isn't what I wanna do.

How can I delete it?

Thank you,I finally solved this problem by use NoSQL Manager for mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to mongo from terminal/command prompt then follow steps as below

1. `use d:mongo`
2. `db.dropDatabase()`

Comment: that db named 'd:mongo',neither I use 'use db_name_containing_:d' nor use 'use db_name_containing_:"d"' can work.                                 [thread1] Error: [db_name_containing_:d] is not a valid database name :
Mongo.prototype.getDB@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47:12

Comment: I have edited commands. Please take a look. It worked pefect for me

Comment: > use d:mongo
2016-06-24T11:46:10.480+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: [d:mongo] is not a valid database name :
Mongo.prototype.getDB@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47:12

Comment: are you using terminal?

Comment: I am using mongo shell in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.getSiblingDB("d:mongo").dropDatabase()
```